# Unable to install vulkan on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, unreal-engine4, vulkan

My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce GT 705. On running ./UE4Editor, the error says "Cannot find a compatibe Vulkan device or driver". So, I tried to install Vulkan following this page [Vulkan On Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/install-and-test-vulkan-on-linux#h4-2-ubuntu) . `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo apt upgrade` are may be correct.

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd0000104Csv00001028sd0000109Bbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF119 [GeForce GT 705]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
Hit:1 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]                             
Get:3 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]                                                          
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                               
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal InRelease [23.8 kB]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [7,196 B]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [6,924 B]
Fetched 350 kB in 3s (128 kB/s)                     
Reading package lists... Done
```

but, below is error.

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-396 nvidia-settings vulkan vulkan-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-396
E: Unable to locate package vulkan
```

I don't know why `nvidia-graphics-drivers-396` and `vulkan` don't exist and how I install vulkan. Please tell me about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GT 705 is based on the Fermi architecture, which simply does not support Vulkan. So even with a recent driver you won't be able to use Vulkan with that GPU.

Comment: Where can I find the supported GPUs?

Comment: E.g. on my database at https://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/. Note that this is based on user-contributions, so it's not an official list. Another source is this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)#Compatibility